# how to configure the ethernet link of a pc using a tcl code

Tags: tcl

I am working on my linux machine with Ubuntu 10.04 and Tcl 8.4. I want to have a Tcl script which can configure the ethernet link for this PC. Can any body share the required code for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to handle ethernet configuration is to use Tcl's [`exec`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/exec.htm) command to invoke the commands listed in the [relevant Ubuntu help pages](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/network-configuration.html), with some adaptation to deal with the fact that Tcl's very good at string manipulation itself. (If you're used to bash scripting, note that Tcl's `exec` is quite different. In particular, it doesn't replace the Tcl process; it instead waits for the subprocess to finish and returns its standard output.) For example, you might create a command to list the network interfaces like this:

```
proc listNetworkInterfaces {} {
    foreach line [split [exec ifconfig -a] "\n"] {
        if {[regexp {^(\w+)} $line -> ifc]} {
            lappend result $ifc
        }
    }
    return $result
}

# Demonstrating use...
puts "my network interfaces are [join [lsort [listNetworkInterfaces]] ,]"
```

And you'd set the IP address, netmask and gateway for a link like this (assuming that you run `tclsh yourscript.tcl` inside `sudo`; you *need* administrative privileges to configure networking):

```
proc setNetworkAddress {interface address mask gateway} {
    exec ifconfig $interface $address netmask $mask
    exec route add default gw $gateway $interface
}
```

There are rather a lot of things you can configure on a network interface, but the general principle for easy coding is to use `exec` to call a system tool. It's not quite as fast as other, more-complicated solutions (such as writing a C interface that connects Tcl's script layer directly to the underlying system calls), but it is dead simple to get going with.

Comment: Thanks for this. I will try and let you know soon. Thanks alot. Now can you give me tcl a code which will validate a given ip address and mask address.

Comment: There might be code in Tcllib for that (the [ip](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/tcllib_ip.html) package perhaps?) but it's not a part I've explored thoroughly…